# Getting boolean values from a properties file

Tags: java, properties

I have a properties file with some boolean values. AFAIK, java.util.properties does not have anything like `getBoolean`. Is there any other Java library that can do this? Or maybe there is another way, except of `doAction = "true".equals(yourProperties.getProperty("doaction"));`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) provides that on top of `java.util.Properties`.

```
boolean doAction = config.getBoolean("doaction");
// ...
```

Answer (score 51):

How about using [Boolean.parseBoolean()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) to do the conversion, like this:

```
Boolean foo = Boolean.parseBoolean(yourProperties.getProperty("foo"));
```

At least that way it will be consistent with other Java string to boolean conversions.

I've tested, and this seems to happily convert a missing property (returned as `null`) to `false` which is handy.

Answer (score 14):

When the Properties of your file are loaded you can use the `Boolean`-Class to get the Properties:

```
Boolean.getBoolean("your.property");
```

to retreive the value of the property.

[See JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

There's also the [`java.util.prefs`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html) package, its [**`Preferences`**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) has methods like [`getBoolean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

Answer (score -3):

```
propiedades.setProperty("property", "true");
```

...

```
Boolean.parseBoolean(propiedades.getProperty("property");
```

Comment: I fail to see what this adds over the other answers that were posted 4 years ago.